# Format the content and display media

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a textarea where I can enter the content:

```
<textarea name="content" placeholder="Content"></textarea>
```

The type of the content column in the DB is `Text`.

So I could add text there and then insert that text to the DB:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO content VALUES(?)');
$stmt->execute( [$content] );
```

Then I show that content some where on my website:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT content FROM posts');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $results as $result ){
    echo '<div>'. $result .'</div>';
}
```

But that content is then showed as a plain text, So if I entered:

```
$content = "This content contains a URL http://example.com";
```

I get: `This content contains a URL http://example.com`, So the link is not shown as a link, But a plain text.

Also if I added an image:

```
$content = "http://example.com/images/img.jpg";
```

Or a video:

```
$content = "http://example.com/images/video.mp4";
```

Or a video from Youtube.

So what should I do?

Should I use PHP or Javascript to check if the content contains a URL/image/video, Then add the related html elements to that URL?

Comment: use `CKEditor` instead of `textarea`. It has features to add images, links and others.

Comment: Do you want the users to use a markup language or even a BBCOde like style, or do you only want to replace such data in the frontend while saving the "raw" form?

Comment: @NicoHaase, the users can't add or edit, It's managed by the admin

Comment: Well, whoever the user of that textarea is - what about the rest of my question?

Comment: Why would you use CKEditor to wrap a URL in HTML tags?!! Jeeeez.

Comment: @TheCarver, The admin is a client, He doesn't know html

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using an editor like CKEditor just to wrap some URLs in markup, as others have shockingly suggested. That is a very lazy and expensive (not necessarily price but size of files and number of requests) way of solving a simple task.

The following solution is untested and the regex patterns were taken from external sources, so I unfortunately can't guarantee their correctness. Try it yourself and test, test, test.

**EXAMPLE**

```
// your string

$content = "This is the content https://example.com/images/image1.jpg";

// find all URLs in $content and add matches to $matches array

$regex = "#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#";
preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);

// loop through $matches array

foreach ($matches as $match) {

    // check each item in array and use regex to determine type

    if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i', $match)) {
        $markup = '<img src="'.$match.'">';
    } else {
        $markup = '<a href="'.$match.'">'.$match.'</a>';
    }

    // now replace the $match'ed URL in $content with the right $markup

    str_replace($match, $markup, $content);

}
```

**DOCS**

`preg_match_all`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

`preg_match`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

`str_replace`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php